# How to call different api links within same page?

Tags: api, vue.js

```
import axios from 'axios'                                         

window.axios = require('axios');
export default {
    name: 'Teams',

    data: () => ({
    dataList : [],
    jsonArr: []
  }),
  
  mounted(){
    axios({
      id:31,
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/league/2",
      "headers":{
        "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
        "x-rapidapi-host":"api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key":"d67f727cf5msh4507fcb80b215bbp12e824jsn13d8d45c4d68",
        "useQueryString":true
      }
    })
      .then((response)=>{
        this.dataList = response.data.api.teams
        console.log(this.dataList)
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  },
```

Suppose I want that the api url to changes within my single page, like for one column `teams/league/2`, and for the next column `teams/league/3`.
The id at the end of the url is the only thing that will change. Can you suggest any easy way to get that id changed within a page using a user defined variable or anyother methods?

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your axios call to it's own method:

```
methods: {
  getTeams(id, page) {
    return axios({
      id,
      "method":"GET",
      "url": `https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/league/${page}`,
      "headers":{
        "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
        "x-rapidapi-host":"api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key":"d67f727cf5msh4507fcb80b215bbp12e824jsn13d8d45c4d68",
        "useQueryString":true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

You can then call it from somewhere else with

```
this.getTeams(39, 2).then(response => {
  this.dataList = response.data.api.teams
});
// No catch, since we want to have the actual stack trace and do not handle the error in any way
```